# nodemon not applying changes automatically to the app

Tags: node.js, express, npm, nodemon

When I save changes to the app nodemon says 'restarting due to changes'.
But when I refresh my localhost it does not apply the changes.
Everytime I have to run `nodemon app.js` to see the changes in my app. Why is it happening so?

Below is the **app.js** code:

```
const express = require('express')

// create express app
const app = express();

//register view engine
app.set('view engine','ejs');

//listen for requests
app.listen(3000);

app.use((req,res)=>{

    console.log('new request made');
    console.log('Host:',req.hostname);
    console.log('Path:',req.path);
    console.log('Method:',req.method);

});
//multiple get request handlers for diff webpages
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{

    const blogs = [
        {title: 'Yoshi finds eggs', snippet: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur'},
        {title: 'Mario finds stars', snippet: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur'},
        {title: 'How to defeat bowser', snippet: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur'},
      ];

    res.render('index',{title:'Home',blogs:blogs});  //the path for html webpage is always relative unless provided absolute. the root dir name of the path should be specified.
});

app.get('/about',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('about',{title:'About'});

});

app.get('/blogs/create',(req,res)=>{
    res.render('create',{title:'Create blog'});
});

app.get('/featured',(req,res)=>{

    res.send('<p>Featured page</p>');
});

//redirects 
app.get('/about-us',(req,res)=>{
    res.redirect('/about');          //express send this response to the browser and automatically set status code to 301.
});

//setup 404 page(this functionality always at last beacuse this displays 404 page when any of the above urls is not found)
app.use((req,res) => {
    res.status(404).render('404',{title:'Error 404'});
});
```

**package.json** code:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2"
  }
}
```

Versions:
nodemon 2.0.15,
node v16.13.2,
npm 8.1.2

Comment: Please provide Your code and show the pacakge.json ;-)

Comment: Please look at the code.

Comment: O k;-) Please provide nodemon, node, npm  version ?

Comment: versions provided.

Comment: Did the answer solve your question ?

Answer (score 1):

Restarting server is **one thing**, refreshing browser is **another thing**. For server watching I use `nodemon`. `Nodemon` can see when changes occur in any types of files. But `nodemon` cannot refresh browser page. For this We may use two additional packages - [`connect-livereload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-livereload),[`livereload`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/livereload).

```
npm install connect-livereload livereload
```

Below example:

---

**Folder & File** structure :

[image]

**app.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const livereload = require("livereload");
const connectLivereload = require("connect-livereload");
const express = require("express");
const port = 3000;

const liveReloadServer = livereload.createServer();
liveReloadServer.watch(path.join(__dirname, "views"));

liveReloadServer.server.once("connection", () => {
  setTimeout(() => {
    liveReloadServer.refresh("/");
  }, 50);
});

const app = express();
app.use(connectLivereload());

app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("index");
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", { title: "About" });
});

//listen for requests
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is  listening at http://localhost:${port}`);
});
```

**index.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ejs & express</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div>
        <h1>This is great and it works perfectly!</h1>
        <p>Welcome to using EJS with nodemon and livereload</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**about.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>ejs & express</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <div>
        <h1>This is great and it works perfectly!</h1>
        <p>Welcome to About Page !</p>
      </div>
    </main>
  </body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon app.js -e ejs",
    "watch": "nodemon --ext ejs",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "connect-livereload": "^0.6.1",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.2",
    "livereload": "^0.9.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  }
}
```

---

### npm run watch

We run **app.js** with command `npm run watch`

Now it works like a charm !

**Output** :

[image]